# Node.js android sdk not found error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I am trying to develop a cordova project. I have already installed Android studio with SDK in location

```
C:\Users\Kushi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2
```

In this sdk2 I have installed all packages as well. And also i have all necessary ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES created(as in the image). Still i get this error saying that "Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable" Please answer ASAP.
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Must be, he's saving his sdk in AppData\local\, plus the back slashes. OP, why you saving your SDK in AppData\local\?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your SDK in a better location, such as
   C:\Users\Kushi\AndroidSDK, instead of AppData\Local.
2. In **CMD**, try

   ```
   set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kushi\AndroidSDK

   set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
   ```

Assuming you indeed saved your SDK as AndroidSDK at C:\Users\Kushi

Comment: Thanks for answering. My issue was I have not added all components in PATH variable. Added everything and it worked!!

Comment: Good to hear - IDE setup is always difficult.